# xml class object get child nodes count using (lamba-> or other optimized) iteration java

Tags: java, xml, lambda, iteration, java-stream

I have a soa xml java object, in which I need to get the total count of SItemDetails which is 4 here:

```
<ns57:PProductsResponse xmlns:ns57="">
    <ResponseInfo xmlns="" TransactionId="test"/>
    <ns57:PProductsSuccess>
        <ONumber xmlns="" ONumber="7">
            <OItemNumber>
                <PItemDetails Price="0.00" >
                    <SItemDetails FIdRef="01-01" SId="12D"/>
                    <SItemDetails FIdRef="01-02" SId="10F"/>
                </PItemDetails>
            </OItemNumber>
        </ONumber>
    </ns57:PProductsSuccess>
    <ns57:PProductsSuccess>
        <ONumber xmlns="" ONumber="7">
            <OItemNumber>
                <PItemDetails Price="0.00">
                    <SItemDetails FIdRef="01-02" SId="10G"/>
                    <SItemDetails FIdRef="01-01" SId="12E"/>
                </PItemDetails>
            </OItemNumber>
        </ONumber>
    </ns57:PProductsSuccess>
</ns57:PProductsResponse>
```

```
PProductsSuccessType[] pProductSuccess = pProductsResponse.getPProductsResponse().getPProductsSuccess();
long sItemDetailsCount1 = Arrays.stream(pProductSuccess).filter(PProductsSuccessType 
                        -> (PProductsSuccessType.getONumber().getOItemNumber()[0].getPItemDetails().getSItemDetails()!=null)).count();
```

OR

```
long sItemDetailsCount2 = Arrays.stream(pProductSuccess)
                        .flatMap(p -> Arrays.stream(p.getONumber().getOItemNumber()))
                        .filter(o -> o.getPItemDetails().getSItemDetails() != null).count();
```

OR

```
long sItemDetailsCount3 = Arrays.stream(pProductSuccess)
                    .map(p -> p.getONumber().getOItemNumber())
                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .count();
```

When I executed the above codes it gave the result as 2 but i am expecting 4 since we have 4 SItemDetails in the pProductsResponse.

Can someone help me achieve it using lamda iteration.

Comment: You're only counting the number of pProductSuccess that meet that filter criteria. 
Your filter is going to return a stream of PProductsSuccessType that meet your criteria of SItemDetails not being null. 
You will need to use .map() and flatmap to transform your stream into a stream<SItemDetails> and then call .count()

Comment: Updated my question with additional codes samples I have tried. I am not familiar in using Lambda I am new to it.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda expression is just an anonymous function. It doesn't look like lambda's are your issue here. It looks like you're confused on what your streams are doing.

I'd suggest reading through https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams-introduction to get a better understanding of using the streams api.
Your IDE should already do this for you but each method chained together below is returning an object. Map and flatmap both return Stream<>. I've added some comments of what I can guess is being returned from your method calls.

```
long sItemDetailsCount3 = Arrays.stream(pProductSuccess) //Stream<pProductSuccess>
                    .map(p -> p.getONumber().getOItemNumber()) //Stream<List<OItemNumber>>
                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream) // Stream<OItemNumber>
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // Stream<OItemNumber>
                    .count(); //The number of items in the Stream<OItemNumber>
```

As you can see, your count would be returning the count of OItemNumber's since that's what the stream is iterating over.

To get the SItemDetails we need to have a stream of SItemDetails. This *should* work for your needs. I am using flatmap since I assume your getters are returning a Collection<> of items. In short, flatmap will flatten the collection and give a Stream while map would give 
`Stream<List<item>>`

```
Arrays.stream(pProductSuccess) //Stream<pProductSuccess>
                    .flatmap(p -> p.getONumber().getOItemNumber().stream()) //Stream<OItemDetails>
                    .flatmap(oItemNumber -> oItemNumber.getPItemDetails().stream())//Stream<PItemDetails>
                    .flatmap(pItemDetail -> pItemDetail.getSItemDetails().stream())//Stream<SItemDetails>
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // Stream<SItemDetails>
                    .count();
```

If you are ever confused about what is being returned from a stream, remove the method chaining and do something similar to

```
Stream<OItemNumber> oItemNumberStream = Arrays.stream(pProductSuccess)
                    .flatmap(p -> p.getONumber().getOItemNumber().stream())
Stream<> anotherStream = oItemNumberStream.flatmap(....);
```

By assigning local variables it is easier to see what object is returned from each call. Your IDE should help do this by displaying what would be returned on each line as long as you format your code so a method call is each on it's own line (as shown in your examples above).